# Почему не подключает файл css3-mediaqueries.js?

Tags: css3, internet-explorer, css

Здравствуйте!
Я подключил сию конструкцию

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

внутри `head` для использования `mediaqueries` в эксплорере 7-8, но при запуске в 8-ом (а точнее в 9-ом, но в режиме 8-го) страница зависает, почему?

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно веб-интерфейс SVN'овых репозиториев использовать в качестве CDN, наверняка там стоит блок на такое использование по Referer'у.

[Вот так](https://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/files/css3-mediaqueries.js) уже немного лучше. А вообще лучше всего поищите CDN, на котором эта либа выложена. Или уж положите к себе.

Comment: Друг, ты разговариваешь на непонятном мне языке:) Я не разбираюсь в яваскрипте, я просто воспользовался готовым средством для медиазапросов, но оно почему-то не действует.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond

Действует аналогично,даже лучше.
Я когда-то спрашивал https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13251649/media-queries-for-ie

Comment: Знаю про эту штуку, но ее надо как-то на сервере устанавливать, а как, не знаю. Там по английский, а я не владею в достаточной степени. Не подскажешь, как его установить?